# How to record the status of steps in a process?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a web application that takes input from a user and uses it to generate a report based on the results of calling various external web services.

I want to track the progress of the report generation, being able to see the status, start time and stop time of each step.

I've added the domain objects `Job` and `JobStep`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="jobs")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false, of={ "id" })
@ToString()
public class Job extends DomainObject {
  @NotNull
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="job_id")
  private Set<JobStep> steps = new TreeSet<JobStep>();

  protected Job() {/*Hibernate requirement*/}

  public Job() {
    // Create all the steps in the beginning with the default settings:
    // status=waiting, date_time both null.
    for (JobStep.Type stepType : JobStep.Type.values()) {
      JobStep step = new JobStep(stepType);
      steps.add(step);
    }
  }

  public Set<JobStep> getSteps() {
    return steps;
  }

  public void startStep(JobStep.Type stepType)
  {
    for (JobStep step : steps) {
      if (step.getType() == stepType) {
        step.start();
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  public void stopStep(JobStep.Type stepType, JobStep.Status status) {
    for (JobStep step : steps) {
      if (step.getType() == stepType) {
        step.stop(status);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="job_steps")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false, of={ "type", "job" })
@ToString
public class JobStep extends DomainObject implements Comparable<JobStep> {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobStep.class);

  public enum Type {
    TEST_STEP1,
    TEST_STEP2,
    TEST_STEP3
  }

  public enum Status {
    WAITING,
    RUNNING,
    FINISHED,
    ERROR
  }

  @NotNull
  @Getter
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Type type;

  @NotNull
  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Status status = Status.WAITING;

  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  private DateTime start = null;

  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  private DateTime stop = null;

  @ManyToOne
  private Job job;

  protected JobStep() {/*Hibernate requirement */}

  public JobStep(Type type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public void start() {
    assert(status == Status.WAITING);

    status = Status.RUNNING;
    start = new DateTime();
  }

  public void stop(Status newStatus) {
    assert(newStatus == Status.FINISHED ||
           newStatus == Status.ERROR);
    assert(status == Status.RUNNING);

    status = newStatus;
    stop = new DateTime();
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(final JobStep o) {
    return getType().compareTo(o.getType());
  }
}
```

These are manipulated using the `JobService` class:

```
@Service
public class JobService {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobService.class);

  @Autowired
  private JobDAO jobDao;

  @Transactional
  public void createJob() {
    Job job = new Job();
    Long id = jobDao.create(job);

    LOG.info("Created job: {}", id);
  }

  @Transactional
  public Job getJob(Long id) {
    return jobDao.get(id);
  }

  @Transactional
  public void startJobStep(Job job, JobStep.Type stepType) {
    LOG.debug("Starting JobStep '{}' for Job {}", stepType, job.getId());

    job.startStep(stepType);
  }

  @Transactional
  public void stopJobStep(Job job, JobStep.Type stepType,
                          JobStep.Status status) {
    LOG.debug("Stopping JobStep '{}' for Job {} with status {}", stepType,
              job.getId(), status);

    job.stopStep(stepType, status);
  }
}
```

So in a method that starts a step, I can write:

```
class Foo() {

  @Autowired
  JobService jobService;        

  public void methodThatStartsAStep(Job job) {
    jobService.startJobStep(job, JobStep.Type.TEST_STEP1);

    // Implementation here
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is finding a way to give the `Job` instance to the method that requires it in order to record that the step has started.

The obvious solution is to pass the `Job` as a parameter (as above), but it doesn't always make sense passing a `Job` - it's only done to record the step (extreme example below):

```
public int multiplySomeNumbers(Job job, int num1, int num2) {
  jobService.startJobStep(job, JobStep.Type.TEST_STEP1);

  // Implementation here.
}
```

I have two thoughts on an ideal solution:

1. Use an aspect and annotate functions that can cause a change in the job step state. This makes it less coupled, but the aspect would still need to get the job from somewhere;
2. Store the `Job` object or id in a global-like scope (e.g. a session or context). I tried using `@Scope("session")` on my `JobService` with the intention of storing the `Job` instance there, but I kept getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found`. I'm not even sure if this is the right use-case for such a solution.

My questions are:

1. **Is it possible to store the `Job` or its id somewhere so I don't have to add the `Job` as a parameter to method?**
2. **Is there a way of doing this that I'm not aware of?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re: question 2, I'm going to go out on a limb and take the widest definition of that question possible.

You seem to be reimplementing [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/). Batch has extensive support for defining and  executing jobs, persisting job progress, and supporting resumption. It also has contexts for remembering state and moving state from one step to another, chunk-oriented processing, and a generally well thought out and extensive infrastructure, including a bunch of readers and writers for common workflows.

Feel free to ignore this answer, I just wanted to throw the suggestion out there in case it spares you a ton of work.

Comment: This does look very similar, thank-you. I'm not sure if it's appropriate yet so I'll delay accepting until I'm sure.

Comment: I'm not sure my system qualifies as a batch-system. On the one hand, the user inputs data to start the job (interactive), on the other hand, after that the entire thing runs in the background and produces a report (the page polls via ajax until the result is there).

Comment: The scheduling of a batch job and its execution are two different things. Spring Batch, for instance, doesn't deal with scheduling at all. It assumes you'll schedule jobs however you want, e.g. cron, Quartz, Spring Batch Admin, or whatever else you fancy. The requirement for it to not be interactive means that the job doesn't require user interaction during its execution to run to completion.

Comment: `spring-batch` works great for my case. `spring-batch-admin` is a pain to setup, but you can list jobs using the `JobExplorer` interface.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep it in thread local , you can directly access the Object from thread local / Or you can create custom Spring scope  for more info about custom scope http://springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-scope.html .  And you can define the Job in custom Scope and inject that into your beans.

**EDIT** : This will work only if your entire process runs in single thread and  your Job steps are static you can follow the process you mentioned. In case if your Jobs are not static ( mean calling the external services / order of external services may be changed based on input) i would implement Chain responsibility and command pattern ( commands as actual process) and Chain as your Job Steps. then you can track / stop / change the steps based on configuration.